# error referencing an css file called app.css in app.component.html file for Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5.
In my google chrome console I am getting the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/css/app.css 404 (Not Found)

This is my app.component.html:

```
        <html><head><style type="text/css">.ng-animate.item:not(.left):not(.right){-webkit-transition:0s ease-in-out left;transition:0s ease-in-out left}</style><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
      <title>TESTING </title>
      <!--<title ng-bind="title">SLM</title>-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <link href="./css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/31/5/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/31/5/util.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/31/5/stats.js"></script></head>
    <body>

    ALBERT


    </body></html>
```

This is image of my directory structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI11B.png)

How am I referring to the app.css file incorrectly?

What should be the above link structure be?

Answer (score 0):

Your path should refer to the **assets** folder.
e.g. /assets/css/app.css

Comment: This is my index.html:

Comment: Please check for any spelling error in the class name.
Try to change the background of the body to check whether 'app.css' is working as expected or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>KeysManagement</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">.ng-animate.item:not(.left):not(.right){-webkit-transition:0s ease-in-out left;transition:0s ease-in-out left}</style><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.component.html:

```
    <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
    begin Albert Lam
    <div id="social2search_container"></div>
    <div class="toolkit" id="1">
        <div class="header-top" style=" padding-left:4%; padding-right:5%;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 97%;padding-left: 7%;padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 11px;">
            <!-- Logo and Title -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="float: right;margin-right: 175px;">
                <div class="logo">
                <div class="logo1">

                    <p class="large">
                    <strong>
                        Welcome to TEST Canada
                    </strong><br>
                    The Global Language of Business
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    End Albert Lam
```

In my app.component.html I am trying to reference css class "toolkit" in "assets/css/app.css"? But it seemed not able to reference this css class?